# MFC VC++ : Picture Control fails to load PNG images

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, png

I use the following code for loading PNG image into a Picture Control.

```
....
LPSTREAM pStrmDefImg = TurnStream(MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceID),_T("PNG"));
if(pStrmDefImg !=  NULL) {
    CImage img;
    img.Load(pStrmDefImg);    // Load from stream
    pictureCtrl.SetBitmap(img);
    pStrmDefImg->Release();
}
.....

LPSTREAM TurnStream(LPCTSTR Resource, LPCTSTR Type)
{
    char* pData = 0;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    int nRes = GetResource(Resource,Type,&pData,&dwSize);              
    LPSTREAM pStream;
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwSize+1);
    void *pImageData = GlobalLock(hGlobal);
    memcpy(pImageData, pData, dwSize);
    HRESULT hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, TRUE, &pStream);
    return pStream;
}
```

Do you see any issues in this code? There is no error thrown, but the picture control does not show the loaded image.

Comment: This code works.. I had to change the `type` in picture control properties. I set it to `Bitmap` and it shows the png image.

Comment: hey, can you tell be about `GetResource(Resource,Type,&pData,&dwSize);` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `type` attribute to `Bitmap` in `PictureCtrl` properties window.